# Scrolling and Changing the view Using Xib

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, paging

I want to implement paging concept for two views,I implemented it and it is working fine, but in that given views, First view should have 2views,and 2 buttons in the navigation bar, if I select one button it will show one view, and for second button it should show second view, I am using Xib to add scroll view, and adding views in that.

Now the issue is i didn't get secondview while selecting the second button in the firstView.

Please guide me to solve this issue.

I am using this code to getting Views in scrollview.

```
       NSArray *views = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:maleCircleView,femaleCircleView, nil];
        for (int i = 0; i < views.count; i++) 
        {
            UIView *subview = [views objectAtIndex:i];
            CGRect frame;
            frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i+10;
            frame.origin.y = subview.frame.origin.y-30;
            frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

            [titleLabel setHidden:YES];
            subview.frame = frame;
            if(i==0)
            {
                UIView *femaleView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
                [femaleView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
                [femaleView setTag:subview.tag+11];
                UIImageView *sample = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"save.png"]];
                sample.frame = CGRectMake(250, 50, 50, 50);
                [femaleView addSubview:sample];
                NSLog(@"femaleView:%@",femaleCircleView);
                [self.scrollView addSubview:femaleView];
                [femaleView addSubview:maleCircleView];
//               [femaleView setHidden:YES];
            }
            NSLog(@"subview:%@",subview);
            [self.scrollView addSubview:femaleCircleView];

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `bringSubviewToFront` method.

```
 [self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourSelectedView];
```

I think it will be helpful to you.